# trigger function when receive email on nodejs/express

Tags: node.js, express, imap

I am trying to build a ticketing system where when customer send email to example@support.com, it will automatically convert the email into new ticket for agent to attend to or update the ticket when customer reply to the email. I am having trouble finding the correct library/framework/ways for triggering a function when my inbox receive an email.

I found the node-imap way but then its manually calling an function to see if there are new email (so if I check once every 1 minute it would result in >43000 API call a month). Is they any way to trigger a function automatically when I receive an email in the inbox (or any other way for me to explore)?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Check if your email provider allows plugins/scripts on the SMTP side of the transaction. IMAP is not really the tool for it, but can be used when everything else fails.

Comment: I am using nodemailer with goggle business account and upon checking I don't think they do